# How to import web3 utils in front end Javascript

Tags: web3js, javascript

I need to use a web3.utils.soliditySha3 function in my javascript but web3.utils gives:

```
Cannot read property 'soliditySha3' of undefined
```

My script can't use .require as well. I tried:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js@1.0.0-beta.34/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
```

to no avail. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On web3.js v0.x, you have:

- [web3.sha3](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3sha3)

On web3.js v1.x, you have:

- [web3.utils.sha3](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-utils.html#sha3)
- [web3.utils.soliditySha3](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-utils.html#soliditysha3)

You will therefore need to upgrade from v0.x to v1.x.

Comment: Sorry but how do i do that? i thought that my imported script is already v1+

Comment: @bishopqpalzm: Change `1.0.0-beta.34` to `1.2.6` I suppose.

Comment: error in loading web3.min.js: require is not defined. I'm using a Python Flask server instead of npm.

Comment: @bishopqpalzm: I'm not familiar with how things work on the front-end side, but your problem is an older version of web3 which does not support `soliditySha3` (and doesn't even have the `utils` module). So you probably want to post a separate question on how to import web3.js v1.2.x on front-end. If you do so, then please consider accepting this answer (if you feel that it has answered your question).